# Image's don't get loaded even when the image path is right in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have a Laravel application which I successfully installed. However, the images on the website don't seem to load. Here are some HTML
outputs of the web app:

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" href="https://example.com">
  <img src="https://example.com/uploads/logo/logo_dark.png?1702879417" alt="Logo" />
</a>
```

```html
<div class="theme-avtar">
  <img src="https://example.com/Modules/Account/favicon.png" alt="Favicon" />
</div>
```

The structure of the project directory is like this:
[image]

And the virtual host configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dash/public

    <Directory /var/www/dash/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

It seems like a routing problem from server configuration side and not script-sided.

I tried changing the `<Directory /var/www/dash/public>` to `<Directory /var/www/dash>` and I also tried `php artisan storage:link` but neither fixed the issue.

Comment: All code in your post should be posted as *text* and not in the form of images - [Read More](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0):

Your images are outside the document root (which is in `/public`).
So the URL with `/Modules/Account/favicon.png` isn't reachable and
this is normal and safe.

Imagine if the visitors could access your `.env` file with all
the passwords!? Same problem for all the other sensitive data
such as the `vendors`, `storage` (for cache, sessions, etc).

**All your assets (JS, CSS, images, etc) should be placed under the `/public` folder.**

I would suggest to move/copy your images to a folder such as
`/public/img/favicon.png` and create another one like
`/public/uploads/img/` for the uploaded images.

If you change the document root to the project root, it will
probably run because there often is an `.htaccess` file containing
some rewrite rules to make the site "kind of work" properly. I saw
typically something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# If the URL is not starting with /public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
# If the URL is not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the URL is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Then capture the URL and prepend /public in front of it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

# If the URL is empty or just containing the first slash,
# then load public/index.php.
RewriteRule ^/?$ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But as you see, this will not protect your sensitive data!
So **don't set your document root to `/var/www/dash`.**

Comment: Thank you for the details. Is there a command which can transfer all the necessary folders from root (for example Modules, uploads etc ...) to the public?
This is a ready-to-use script which is getting sold on codecanyon. I think somewhere they should've thought about this issue and had a solution for it. Is there some common solutions to this issue?

Comment: Well, I'm rather surprised they made such a config! Just a question: Is the *rewrite* Apache module enabled on your server? Perhaps that `/public/.htaccess` contains some specific rules to make PHP serve some images via a Laravel defined route in the project.
But even if you copy the files, you'll also have to correct these wrong img `src` attributes. I would personally complain to the author of the *Codecanyon* package.

Comment: I've looked through their demo online and everything was fine so i assume i did something wrong in the process. Here is the details `/public/.htaccess` [Link](https://pastebin.com/L6TZ8Ec5) / Also here's the details of `/.htaccess` in the root directory [Link](https://pastebin.com/NNZ1DLEu). Hope you can find something useful. Thank you

Comment: I assume that the answer to my previous question about the *rewrite* module enabled is "Yes". I see that `/.htaccess` is only protecting `.env` and not all the rest. So, for sure, don't set your document root to `/var/www/dash`. In `/public/.htaccess` we see that the URLs `/uploads/logo/logo_dark.png` and `/Modules/Account/favicon.png` will not match existing files (because they are not in the `/public/` folder) so the front controller `/public/index.php` will take over to load Laravel. If no Laraval route is defined to handle theses URLs, you will get 404 errors for them.

Comment: Is the code/demo of the *Codecanyon* available? Did you contact them to ask them why they use images out of the default document root which should be `/public`? Is your `uploads` folder at the correct place? Shouldn't it be at `/public/uploads`? For protected documents (such as PDF, etc), it's normal to store them at the project root folder at `/uploads` because in this case, your *Laraval* app would be in charge of serving them via PHP, respecting user access rules. But for assets of a theme, no PHP should be loaded to serve them. It's Apache that should serve them for performance reasons.

Comment: Here is the [Link](https://apps.rajodiya.com/dash/login) to the online demo. for example if you inspect the logo image on top menu, you can see the image src is almost the same. The only difference is that the demo is installed inside a folder and not the root directory. I tried reaching out but the support takes too long and i want to address my mistake if there is any. With your help obviously <3

Comment: In the demo, I can't see any image trying to load `Modules/Account/favicon.png`. There are stored in a sub-folder called `images` or in another one called `uploads/logo`, certainly under `public`.
**I notice a 404 error** for `../img/down-arrow.svg` which is declared in `css/custom-auth.css` but is missing on their server. **But why wouldn't you just correct your two images ourself?** It's not long to do: **1)** Create a folder `/public/img` **2)** copy your images in there **3)** Correct the templates where the `<img>` tags are and put the write *src* attribute, like `src="/img/favicon.png"`

Comment: It's not just two images unfortunately. It seems the routing has a issue and i genuinely think its from my side but i cant figure it out. For example in other place in the demo [This Link](https://apps.rajodiya.com/dash/settings#lms-store-sidenav) you can see that there is an image with this url: `<img src="//apps.rajodiya.com/dash/Modules/LMS/Resources/assets/image/logo.png" id="blah5" width="170px" class="img_setting">`

Comment: Or like in [this url])https://apps.rajodiya.com/dash/plans?type=subscription) you can see the image path for each of the modules icon images. Even if i try to manually address all this images, i'm always gonna be afraid that i might've missed something. 
p.s. still haven't heard of the support and i really want to figure it out before they ask same questions.

Comment: Effectively, now, **once logged in**, I can see these URLs to `/dash/Modules/LMS/...`.
I'm sorry, but it will be difficult for us to help you without the source code. The only thing I can see is that they are serving the content from the project root dir, as I can access sensitive data such as [package.json](https://apps.rajodiya.com/dash/package.json) or [modules_statuses.json](https://apps.rajodiya.com/dash/modules_statuses.json) or worse [binaries](https://apps.rajodiya.com/dash/vendor/bin/carbon)... Ugly!

Comment: I assume that's pretty bad then Thank you for the time you put in answering though. Do you by any chance know an purchasable script with the same functionality? (HRM,CRM,Project Management etc...)

Comment: Well, sorry, I don't know any. But the best is to report this security issue and tell them to serve the `/public` folder how one should do. They can then correct all the bad links to assets which are not in the public folder. I could even imagine on a Linux server that one could create a symbolic link in the public folder to access some assets stored outside the document root. Just an idea, but it would avoid having to copy all these assets and have them twice on the disk. Of course, only do that if it's images, CSS, JS and not PHP code or settings.